# Creating objects with the same arguments across the system

Tags: oop, design-patterns, parameters, arguments, instantiation

I have an object that performs a very specific task. To be created, this object needs some parameters. I create a new instance in some parts of my system. But there is the problem. What if a parameter or argument must be changed in the future? I will need to change it everywhere. Then I thought: "Well, maybe I can encapsulate its creation in a class, if some argument changes, I will need to change it just in a single place!".

It does make perfect sense to me. The real question is, is this "wrapper" object a factory? Its responsibility would be "Create a new object with specific parameters and return it". Consumers would just use this object ...

Comment: I suppose this would qualify as a (very simple) factory. Any chance you can specify the parameters externally, and have the factory read them and instantiate accordingly? If so, you may be able to allow modifying the behavior without changing the code at all (at the expense of configuration that may be hard to read/understand).

Comment: Actually it's a single class instantiated with the same arguments everytime ...

Answer (score 0):

You a refactoring code to avoid duplication, that is itself likely to improve your overall maintainability.

If this piece of refactored code is creating objects then, yes, it is a factory. It really doesn't matter what you call it - is your code better structured now you have it? Then do it!

However, given that it is a factory study the classic design patterns concerning factories and  understand what leads people to use more sophisticate forms of this pattern. Decide whether you have any of the forces that lead them to use "clever" factories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe is that all clients of your class have to change when the constructor parameters of that class change. Introducing a factory could help prevent recompilation of the clients. But does this really solve the problem? If you modify the class to be constructed with another parameter that parameter has to be determined somewhere, probably in the context of the clients that initiate the construction. How should the factory class know? Would the clients have to pass any context information to the factory?

What parameters are needed to construct the object? Do the clients provide them or could the objects be created beforehand and then injected into the clients as you would inject the factory (as I understand your question the latter seems to be the case)? Consider using a [DI framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This oftentimes makes factories obsolete.

Why are you afraid that your class is likely to be changed? Could it be that your class just does too much? Mind the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In your case also the [Open/Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) is an interesting study.

As I understand a factory does not necessarily address the problem you describe. Factories take the responsibility of creating objects away from clients so the client doesn't have to know the concrete type of the object. Just preventing that signatures remain stable can also be done by wrapping parameters in a single object. This is also a well known [refactoring pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object). But it also doesn't solve the question where the new parameters come from.